# Hyphenation for "300 or 400 level"

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Since "400 level" should be hyphenated as "400-level", should "300 or 400 level" be hyphenated as "300- or 400-level," or is there another way to write this?

Comment: What comes after it? 400 level is not necessarily hyphenated at all....40-year-old man but: he was 40 years old.

Comment: @Lambie: it's in reference to courses (i.e., "a 400-level course") so it seems necessary.

Comment: Yes, "a 400-level course", same for all the other levels, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"300- or 400-level" is correct.  However, if you have "to" in between, I would write it as "300-to-400 level" or "300-to-400-level".

Comment: Indeed; that's why I edited the original version (I meant to write 'or' and not 'to').

Comment: I think you removed one "to" but not the other.  It's still in "300 to 400 level."    That's why I wasn't sure whether you meant to use "or" or "to."